# How to set a query scope for Model::All rows returned in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model class named `Car` =>  `$car = new Car;` attached to a MySQL table.

and I'm fetching all table rows using `Car::All();`

further, I'm also writing a query scope for fetching "diesel" engine cars only, as below

```
public function scopeGetDieselEngineCars($query){

        $query->where("engine_type","=","Diesel");

}
```

But, on running `Car::All()->getDieselEngineCars()` . This gives a function not found error.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope setup is right. However, you need to first apply the scope, then get the results:

```
Car::getDieselEngineCars()->get();
```

It should work for your case.

Comment: I get this error when i'm running the function `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

Comment: @wolfgang try using `get()`